# How to eliminate racing conditions for elements with autopostback=true in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, asp.net-ajax, race-condition, autopostback

We develop using Sharepoint, therefore we have to stick to ASP.NET 3.5.
In case if our page have field with autopostback and a button we encounter race conditions as soon as user was on autopostback field and clicks the button.
In this case button click sometimes returns earlier than autopostback’s one and therefore is being overridden.

Did anyone experience this issues before?

What is the right solution for it?

ADDON:
The case I'm talking about is about the following:

```
<form>
<ScriptManager />
<UpdatePanel>
<TextBox AutoPostBack="True" />
<Button />
</UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

Comment: What requires an Auto Postback prior to the form being submitted? Is it like a "username already exists" validation? What breaks that you can't solve in the button event.

Comment: Please, see my comments to the first answer. We are building generic framework, so there can be any number of fields with AutoPostback on the page. Solution has to be generic in our case.

Comment: @Artem - Just read the common, I don't understand what the fields that have auto-postback do, so it's hard to answer your question. It sounds like you're using autopostback for the wrong reasons if each field is dependent on the previous, or submitting the form is dependent on the result of the postbacks...

Comment: Are you sure that the other event is being overridden? It should not be. Exactly what kind of control are you talking about? Please give us enough detail to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Updated the question with example.

Comment: @Artem: but which events are you talking about? Please add the events to your example. For instance, are you watching OnTextChanged?

Answer (score 0):

The most basic solution I can think of is to disable the button using javascript by handling the client event that's causing the autopostback.

Comment: Then we will have to disable the whole page, since the page could have other autopostback fields which will lead to the same conditions. Therefore we will eliminate all advantages of AJAX. :( May be you can advice not-so-simple solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the button while waiting on the postback. But that's a hack and you probably don't want to do that. Typically, I'd expect that the controls would do their validation and block the submission if there's a problem.

Let's say you had an autopostback on a drop-down box where it toggles a textbox for some sub-category info in certain cases. Either the autopostback happens and updates the textbox first, or the submit will submit with the new value of the drop-down and the server-side validation will determine if you needed to have a value in that sub-textbox. If you did, it would return with it enabled and possibly some red text saying it's required.